# Fixing link to shared Picasa album sent by someone else

Tags: picasa-web-albums

My daughter sent me a link to access her Picasa photos but the link isn't working.  There is a problem with the link and she is on a boat in the middle of the Pacific Ocean.  How do I correct the link to access her photos?

Comment: This is delicate, because we cannot help you to correct the link unless you share it, but probably you don't want other people to see your daughter's pics.

Answer (score 4):

Since you probably don't want to share the link for correction, I advise you to:

- Create a new user in Picasa
- Create a new web album with at least 1 picture in it
- Share the album with your real Google user

Now you should try and compare the two links to see if you can find what is missing from your daughter's link.